# How to create a mixed Array inside an Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm new to android and I need some help to create an mixed array inside an array.

This is what I need:

```
myArray = {["String", int, int, int], ["String", int, int, int], ["String", int, int, int]};
```

How can I create something like that? and how can I access to these variables later?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Do you really need an Array or can you use a List, or even a List of Lists?

Comment: Can you create an array of objects of a class you create to hold the `String` and 3 `int`s?

Comment: Since you already know structure `"String", int, int, int` of data you want to put in array why don't you create separate type (class) for it and make array of this class `YourClass[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myArray = {["String", int, int, int], ["String", int, int, int], ["String", int, int, int]};`

=>
make a class to store the data

```
public class MyClass
{
    private String string;
    private int int1;
    private int int2;
    private int int3;

    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public MyClass(String string, int int1, int int2, int int3)
    {
        this.string = string;
        this.int1 = int1;
        this.int2 = int2;
        this.int3 = int3;
    }

    public String getString()
    {
        return string;
    }

    public MyClass setString(String string)
    {
        this.string = string;
        return this;
    }

    public int getInt1()
    { 
        return int1;
    }
    ...
}
```

=> use collections

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
list.add(new MyClass("Hello", 1, 2, 3);
list.add(new MyClass("World", 4, 5, 6);
MyClass mc = list.get(0);
for(MyClass myClass : list)
{
    android.util.Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Content: " + myClass.getString() + " " + myClass.getInt1() + " " + myClass.getInt2() + " " + myClass.getInt3());
}
```

Comment: This answer helps me a lot to solve my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome! If you're curious to know what exactly is going on, I can add some extra comments so you'll know the terms (constructor, field encapsulation and getters setters, etc. Unless you actually know what those are, anyways.)

Answer (score 2):

You make an array of an object

that object contains variables for a `String`, `int`, `int`, `int`

```
ArrayList<MyObject> mArrayList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

mArrayList.add(new MyObject("String1", 1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the answer from Zhuinden was more complete and helps me to understand better.

Comment: @Andresaurus You should accept whichever answer you prefer by clicking the check-mark next to the voting buttons.

Comment: @Andresaurus, struggling makes you stronger; someone else writing the entirety of the code for you doesn't.

Comment: @Akshay Thank you so much, I didn't know that. I'm new at this web, and I think it's amazing. Thanks everyone for your help.
PS: Sorry for my english. I Hope you can understand. =)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I didn't write the entireity of the code though, I provided an example that provided information about multiple things that are necessary and essential to make it work and more, such as using `List` as static type and `ArrayList` as dynamic, constructors, setters that allow method chaining, foreach loop iteration, and the android logging mechanism because many people tend to not know about it. I see nothing wrong with providing information. If we were always stingy about how much we're willing to help newbies, no one would ever learn anything.

Comment: @Zhuinden, my comment wasn't directed @ you; I was pointing out what I believe to be true; you have the freedom to post what you like under the rules. It's not about being stingy, it's about drawing a line between teaching/guiding and hindering one's development, but more over the last sentence is an obvious logical fallacy.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Fair enough :) it's true, if someone does *everything* for you, you will learn nothing. Problem solving is essential, but sometimes guidance is more effective than letting someone stumble around on their own.